# Docker service start (Time stamp)

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am killing and restarting docker service/s inside my code .
**Could I find the timestamp of  docker service restart**  to make sure if the sure was restarted.

Comment: Whats the "code" that is runnig this? sh/bash? What output do you require? For all containers or a single container?

Comment: @dkanejs I am running python file inside which killing/restarting containers(docker service start ....) . I require for single container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

docker service inspect (container name) gives the desired output

Comment: I have only `"CreatedAt":` and `UpdatedAt` but nothing about last restart of service containers.